# Missing Values in Crop identification using Python?

Tags: python, land-classification, clip, time-series, missing-data

I am developing a Python based process that classify crops via time series analysis. Due to clouds there are many missing values. My problem is how to assign a value to these pixels that would be near the real value.

What is the best interpolation method to do this?

I have though of mean value of same month's rasters, but this seems as not a scientific method to me.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/271937/edit) your question to specify in detail what your input data is.

Comment: Reflectance values or an index value?